# How to inspect auto closing window with developer tools?

Tags: web, google-chrome-devtools

I'm attempting to view the network flow of a page in Chrome dev tools. I'm on a page and click the download button to download a file. A new tab is then opened, the file is downloaded, and the new tab is immediately closed. I've tried setting event breakpoints on the first page for Window -> window.close and Load -> unload, and I also have dev tools automatically open for new tabs, but the events are not triggered anyway.

Can I somehow pause the execution when the new tab is opened to view the network activity?

Comment: There might be an extension for this. Otherwise I would use a MitM proxy like Fiddler to add `<script>debugger</script>` to the response html which would work if devtools is set to auto-open.

Comment: I resolved to using Wireshark. It doesn't really adress my question, but it helped solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

Try running this code in the DevTools Console:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e){
  debugger;
});
```

Run that code before you click the download button.